# from gcm.models import get_device_model ImportError: No module named models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I got a sample Django Rest project. When I run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get the error:

```
from gcm.models import get_device_model
ImportError: No module named models
```

in line

```
from gcm.models import get_device_model
```

What is the problem with this line? please help. I am a newbie in python as well as to Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the gcm directory doesn't have a models.py defined.

Somehow you have an issue with your paths.